# How to one activity over another..?

Tags: android

Instead of starting a new activity from the current activity, I want to show the new activity over another so that both the activity should visible and the new activity will be shown over the older one(not occupying all the area of the screen).

Comment: Did you have a question? This forum is for asking specific coding questions.

Comment: This a question ofcourse

Comment: i don't think that any thing is bad in this question and offcourse this is a question and ya it's not looking fully technical but it is a good question for a new android developer i don't know y people are making nagative it's really not apprecialting new developers@BlaineAnderson

Comment: No, this is not a question. This is a statement. You saying that you want to do something, may be an implicit question, but it is not a question. Please read this, so that you be able to get better responses and the help that you need. If you just say that you are doing something and expect others to "read-between-the-lines", you won't get the help that you need. @Aamir, I'm a new developer, and I have had similar experiences, it has made me stronger. If you are worried about the future, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 8):

in style.xml use

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

    </style>
```

in Manifest File use

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivityName"

            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
             />
```

and now make a layout that is smaller then full screen..

What you have ask in comment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/StatusImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:visibility="visible" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

the image will be seen on upper activity..like a dialogue, You can make any layout you want, like this.

Comment: Thanks..!!
What I want is, one Activity on the top of another activity such that the top one should not occupy whole screen and in the remaining area the part of older activity should be visible.(Just like a dialog box over an activity)

Answer (score 5):

You want to set on activity to another say you want to set `activity2` over `activity1` than one way to make such layout is that in manifest file you can define activity like this

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

So here code `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` will let your activity 2 come over activity1 as a dialog.

And I suggest you to take background image of Activity 2 layout to be transparent so that you can achieve your goal

I am not sure that this will solved your issue 100% but I think this is way way by which you can achieve your goal.

Comment: Heavy thanks aamir..!
How to take background image of Activity 2 layout to be transperent..?

Comment: you can tell your designer to make such background image and you don't need to do any think just set that transperent image as a background to activity2 layout and that's it

Comment: What I want is, one Activity on the top of another activity such that the top one should not occupy whole screen and in the remaining area the part of older activity should be visible.(Just like a dialog box over an activity).

Comment: it can be done u need to decrease hieght of secound activity layout and it's posible to do search on google