# how to show an activity over another on half of the screen in the right position?

Tags: android

I am new in android.
I have 2 activities and I want to show the second activity over the first one, but the second activity has a layout:width : 250dp and layout height is fill-parent(fill the screen) and start from the right of the screen.
How can I do that?

I want something like this

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ePpO.jpg)

Comment: You want to have Two activities accesable at one time?

Comment: Try with fragments

Answer (score 1):

You can make a transparent theme for the second activity so it is shown as a floating window. Then for the second activity, restrict the width of the view layout inside a Viewgroup that defines the position.

Here is my style definition for the Transparent theme. Setting this, f.e. in the Manifest `<activity>` declaration, makes it possible to achieve a floating activity on top of the other:

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

The layout is like this, for example, showing a CardView from the right (end):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end">
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I wonder why you would fixate the width to 250, what would happen on bigger/smaller devices? Maybe better to define a margin or padding...?

Comment: Hmmm, I figured there is a duplicate question (closed) with a similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11359154/526592

Comment: Hmmm, this saved my 2 days. I remember that I faced this issue before, but this time still took time